# Use same hotkey in several workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, hotkeys

I have a VBA script in several workbook templates that unlocks the current (active) worksheet. I use the same hotkey so that the users who are permitted to use the macro don't have to remember which hotkey allows them to unlock the workbook.

This generally causes no headaches as most users don't have more than one workbook open at a time (and in all likelihood don't use the hotkeys anyway). The issue is if I have more than one workbook open and try to run the VBA script with the hotkey, I'm currently getting a random instance of the VBA script. This causes problems because the password does vary between the workbooks, so if the hotkey kicks off the VBA script in WB X and I'm in WB Y, I get an error.

Getting to the point, is there a way I can make it so that the VBA script from the active workbook on that hotkey is the one that's used?

Per Alter's request here's a sanitized version of my lock_unlock VBA script

```
Sub Lock_Unlock()
     Dim CurrentUser As String 'holds the current users Windows login
     Dim Approved As String
     Approved = "|user1|user2|user3|"
```

`'Give CurrentUser it's value
 CurrentUser = Environ$("username")

'Check if the user is approved
If InStr(1, Approved, CurrentUser) > 0 Then
    'The user can use this macro. Check if the sheet is currently locked
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
        'It is, unlock
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=PW()
    Else
        'It isn't, relock
        ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        False, Password:=PW()
    End If
'Not a user approved to use this macro, don't do anything
End If

End Sub

Function PW() As String
PW = "password"
End Function`

Comment: I would be highly interested in the code if you are willing to include it. I have a similar problem that I need to solve and it could save me a lot of time if I use yours as a basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it, modularize the password to a getFunction.

ex.

```
Function getPassword()
    getPassword = "password1"
End Function
```

Now, when you want the password call `Application.Run(ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!getPassword")` This will make sure the password is retrieved from the active workbook, regardless of the workbook your macro is being run from

Ex.

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox Application.Run(ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!getPassword")
End Sub

Function getPassword()
    getPassword = "hello"
End Function
```

Option 2: check if ThisWorkbook is the ActiveWorkbook, if it isn't then call the macro from the activeworkbook using the same method I used to get the password.

Comment: D'oh! Why didn't I think of that? I actually already have the password passed back from a function like you suggest (makes it easier to update it every now and then). Thanks for the help!